# Comet mass loss

Tags: comets, mass

As the comet orbits around the Sun, I gather that its tail loses mass due to solar wind and tidal waves. Approximately, from what distance (with respect to Sun) will the mass loss begin?

Answer (score 2):

The mass loss begins at approximately 450-600 million kilometers from the sun. This begins roughly in an area between the end of the asteroid belt and 1 AU from Jupiters orbit.

Extract from wikipedia:

> The coma is generally made of H
>   2O and dust, with water making up to 90% of the volatiles that outflow from the nucleus when the comet is within 3 to 4 astronomical units (450,000,000 to 600,000,000 km; 280,000,000 to 370,000,000 mi) of the Sun. [Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet)